# Why when I create a fulltext index does my match / against query return no results?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I've created a `FULLTEXT` index ...

```
ALTER TABLE pads ADD FULLTEXT search (Keywords, ProgramName, English45)
```

ProgramName is a Varchar however, even if I don't add that in the index I still get no results. In my list of indexes Cardinality is 1 for this index.

Heres the query I'm using.

```
select PadID from Pads WHERE MATCH(keywords,ProgramName,English45) 
 AGAINST('games')
```

However, this is my goal.

```
select PadID from Pads WHERE MATCH(keywords,ProgramName,English45) 
 AGAINST('games') AND RemovemeDate = '2001-01-01 00:00:00' 
 ORDER BY VersionAddDate DESC
```

Here's my Pads Table fields.
[image]

***I need my query to return the word where it occurs as part of the three fields.***

Comment: Can you post the "SHOW CREATE TABLE" results

Comment: Is 'games' a frequent occurence? It might have reached MySQL's threshold for being a stop word and therefore won't be searchable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  guess, you can try

```
MATCH(keywords,ProgramName,English45) 
AGAINST('games' in boolean mode)
```

**default search behavior**

> A natural language search interprets the search string as a phrase in natural human language (a phrase in free text). There are no special operators. The stopword list applies. In addition, words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not match. Full-text searches are natural language searches if no modifier is given.

**boolean search**

> A boolean search interprets the search string using the rules of a special query language. The string contains the words to search for. It can also contain operators that specify requirements such that a word must be present or absent in matching rows, or that it should be weighted higher or lower than usual. Common words such as “some” or “then” are stopwords and do not match if present in the search string. The IN BOOLEAN MODE modifier specifies a boolean search